# Moq a property of concrete class with another moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to create a mock of a concrete class and mock one of its properties with another mock.

```
public class MyClass
{
  public virtual IAdapter Adapter {get; internal set;}
}
```

Testing...

```
var adapter = new Mock<IAdapter>();
adapter.Setup(a => a.WaitForDigit()).Returns(1);
var myClass = new Mock<MyClass>();
myClass.Setup(c => c.Adapter).Returns(adapter.Object); //throws exception
```

It throws the following exception:
*System.ArgumentException: Constant does not match the defined type*

How can I fix that?

**Edit:**

I've changed the design and even then it's still throwing the same exception

```
public class MyClass
{
  public virtual IAdapter Adapter {get;set;}
  public MyClass(IAdapter adapter)
  {
    Adapter = adapter;
  }
}

var adapter = new Mock<IAdapter>();
adapter.Setup(a => a.WaitForDigit()).Returns(1);
var myClass = new MyClass(adapter.Object); //throws exception

System.ArgumentException: Constant does not match the defined type.
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.SetConstantValue(ModuleBuilder module, Int32 tk, Type destType, Object value)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.ParameterBuilder.SetConstant(Object defaultValue)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.MethodEmitter.DefineParameters(ParameterInfo[] parameters)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.MethodEmitter..ctor(AbstractTypeEmitter owner, String name, MethodAttributes attributes, MethodInfo methodToUseAsATemplate)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.AbstractTypeEmitter.CreateMethod(String name, MethodAttributes attributes, MethodInfo methodToUseAsATemplate)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.MethodGenerator.Generate(ClassEmitter class, ProxyGenerationOptions options, INamingScope namingScope)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Contributors.CompositeTypeContributor.ImplementMethod(MetaMethod method, ClassEmitter class, ProxyGenerationOptions options, OverrideMethodDelegate overrideMethod)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Contributors.CompositeTypeContributor.Generate(ClassEmitter class, ProxyGenerationOptions options)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.ClassProxyGenerator.GenerateType(String name, Type[] interfaces, INamingScope namingScope)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.ClassProxyGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GenerateCode>b__0(String n, INamingScope s)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.BaseProxyGenerator.ObtainProxyType(CacheKey cacheKey, Func`3 factory)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.ClassProxyGenerator.GenerateCode(Type[] interfaces, ProxyGenerationOptions options)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.DefaultProxyBuilder.CreateClassProxyType(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, Object[] constructorArguments, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
   at Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory.CreateProxy(Type mockType, ICallInterceptor interceptor, Type[] interfaces, Object[] arguments)
   at Moq.Mock`1.<InitializeInstance>b__24_0()
   at Moq.PexProtector.Invoke(Action action)
   at Moq.Mock`1.InitializeInstance()
   at Moq.Mock`1.OnGetObject()
   at Moq.Mock.GetObject()
   at Moq.Mock.get_Object()
   at Moq.Mock`1.get_Object()
```

Comment: Is MyClass in the same assembly as the test? If not, then the Apapter `internal` setter will not be accessible, which may be confusing Moq.

Comment: If @stuartd is right about the `internal` setter confusing Moq, the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) might help you overcome this problem.

Comment: `MyClass` is not in the same assembly as the test. I've applied `InternalsVisibleToAttribute("MyAssembly.Tests")` to MyClass assembly, but the error is the same.

Comment: Try making the assembly with `MyClass` expose its internals to the Moq assembly via the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`, since it's Moq that will be overriding the class.

Comment: I think there is something to do with: https://github.com/castleproject/Core/issues/141 because `IAdapter` has methods with nullable parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this has nothing to do with `Moq`. It is a `Castle.Core` bug as reported [here](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/issues/141).

To solve this, I've installed `Castle.Core` v4.0 beta package.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a design issue to me.  If you have a dependency on another class then that dependency shouldn't be public.  See here

[Should injected dependencies be publicly accessible or private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839935/should-injected-dependencies-be-publicly-accessible-or-private)

Once that dependency is wrapped and there is no external access, there is no reason to have to moq this dependency.  Your moq'ed methods for MyClass should be sufficient.

Comment: You're totally right. But I can change the design right now and I wanted to know why the moq was throwing that error.

Comment: I've changed the design a little bit, and the exception persists.